# Handling DropDown Menu

Tags: javascript, select, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu in my html, and what I want is when the menu is changed, a JS function is called sending the selected value. What I have right now is this:

HTML/PHP:

```
<select name="selectSquad" class="SquadWeaponSelector" id="selectSquad" onchange="javascript:showWeaponEditorWindow(this.form.selectSquad);">
<?PHP
   $max = $squadNumbers - 1;
   $i = 0;
   while($i <= $max){
      echo "<option value=\"".$names_split[$i]."\"/>".$names_split[$i]."</option>";
      $i++;
   }
?>
</select>
```

JavaScript - what I want to happen:

```
function showWeaponEditorWindow(squad){
   if(squad == "A PHP Value - Jack"){
      alert("jack selected");
   }
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
you need to assign `squad.value` in your condition.

```
<select name="selectSquad" class="SquadWeaponSelector" id="selectSquad" onchange="showWeaponEditorWindow(this);">


function showWeaponEditorWindow(squad){
   if(squad.value == "A PHP Value - Jack"){
     alert("jack selected");
  }
}
```

Update:

you could use `selectedIndex` to get the selected menu rember the the menu index starts at 0;

so change `squad.value` to

```
(squad.selectedIndex == 1)
```

Comment: Nice to see someone not jump straight to jQuery for a straightforward javascript task

Comment: Thanks david. What about if I wanted to use the position of the value? EG: if squad.position selected == 1

Comment: The reason for this is because my drop down menu is dynamic ... so there is no way of knowing what will be in there

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use jQuery for this purpose. You can write:

```
$('#selectSquad').change(function(){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
   // Do anything here with the selectedValue variable
});
```